# Enumeration Objects (Strings) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, icons, constants

I am building a model with Entity Framework and purchased responsive CSS.

The built in fixed icons comes with CSS. Like as follows `(Name and Icon Class Value)`

[image]

I need a way to keep the **names of icons as fixed enums** to access it from the **VS intellisense**. Currently we can't store as a entity table in entity framework (as it require relationship with tables difficult to maintain) and enum doesn't allows string type.

Code that did not work:

```
    public sealed class IconType
    {
        public static readonly IconType Rupee_Icon = new IconType("rupee-icons");
        public static readonly IconType Doller_Icon = new IconType("doller-icon");

        private IconType(int EnumID,string EnumObjectValue)
        {            
            IconValue = EnumObjectValue;
        }

        public string IconValue { get; private set; }
    }
```

More code that did not work (CSS class names contains whitespaces like `ui bell icon`):

```
public enum Icon
{
        NotSet=0,
        Idea  Icon=1,
        Bell Icon =2
}
```

Is there any other ways to use names / objects as enums or constants in EF for easy intellisense in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Omit the white spaces in the enums:

   ```
   public enum Icon
   {
       NotSet = 0,
       IdeaIcon = 1,
       BellIcon = 2
   }
   ```
2. Add a description or name (Or even some custom attribute) attributes to the enums:

   ```
   public enum Icon
   {
       NotSet = 0,

       [Description("ui idea icon")]
       IdeaIcon = 1,

       [Description("ui bell icon")]
       BellIcon = 2
   }
   ```
3. When needed get the description name. Example method to get the description attribute value:

   ```
       public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue)
       where T : struct, IConvertible
   {
       var type = enumerationValue.GetType();
       if (!type.IsEnum)
       {
           throw new ArgumentException("EnumerationValue must be of Enum type", "enumerationValue");
       }

       // Tries to find a DescriptionAttribute for a potential friendly name for the enum
       var memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumerationValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
       if (memberInfo.Length > 0)
       {
           var attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
           if (attributes.Length > 0)
           {
               // Pull out the description value
               return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
           }
       }

       // If we have no description attribute, just return the ToString of the enum
       return enumerationValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using string constants?

```
public static class IconType
{
    public const string RUPEE_ICON = "rupee-icon";
    public const string DOLLER_ICON = "doller-icon";
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the icon's as plain old objects. Why make use of entity framework at all?

```
public static class Icons
{
    public enum Type
    {
        IdeaIcon = 1,
        BellIcon =2
    }

    public static Icon Get(Type type)
    {
        return IconCollection.Single(icon => icon.Type == type);
    } 

    static IEnumerable<Icon> IconCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Icon>
            {
                new Icon(Type.IdeaIcon, "Idea Icon", "icon idea-icon"),
                new Icon(Type.BellIcon, "Bell Icon", "icon bell-icon"),
            };
        }
    }

    public class Icon
    {
        public Icon(Type type, string description, string cssClass)
        {
            Type = type;
            Description = description;
            CssClass = cssClass;
        }
        public Type Type { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string CssClass { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Use in code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        var ideaIcon = Icons.Get(Icons.Type.IdeaIcon);
        var x = ideaIcon.CssClass;
        var y = ideaIcon.Description;

        var bellIcon = Icons.Get(Icons.Type.BellIcon);
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Razor view:

```
@Icons.Get(Icons.Type.BellIcon).CssClass
```

If you needed to enumerate over the icon collection you could easily add another static accessor to the `Icons` class.